# Reduce Plot3D evaluation time?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, timing

I have a large function `func[a,b]` and I need its `Plot3D`. Since the command `Plot3D[func[a,b],{a,a0,a1},{b,b0,b1}]` didn't evaluate even after 10 minutes, I tried the following:

```
In:  Timing[func[aValue,bValue]]
Out: {2.02, someValue}
```

So it takes ~2 seconds for the function at a single point. Then, I tried the following, expecting it to evaluate `func` no more than 2 times (~ 4 seconds)

```
In:  Timing[Plot3D[func[a,b], {a,a0,a1}, {b,b0,b1}, PlotPoints->2, Mesh->All, MaxRecursion->0]]
Out: {24.48, somePlot}
```

I do not see why it takes such a huge amount of time in spite of specifying only two plot-points.

Question:(1) What can I do in this case to make the plotting faster? (2) What is done in general to make plotting faster?

Thank you!

Comment: Try using `ListPlot3D`, instead, i.e. evaluate your points, first, and then feed them to `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: Hard to say without the function. It could be simplified symbolically first, or compiled (with `Compile`), or vectorize, or replaced by a more efficiet algorithm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `PlotPoints -> 2` means 2 plot points in each direction, so I'd expect 4 evaluations for your input (8 seconds total).

We can use `EvaluationMonitor` to see how many times the function is being evaluated:

```
cnt = 0;
Plot3D[a + b, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 2, 
  Mesh -> All, MaxRecursion -> 0, EvaluationMonitor :> (cnt++)
];
cnt
```

> ```
> 16
> ```

`Plot3D` does post processing to make the plot better looking. One part of this is figuring out surface normals to give the plot a smoother appearance, and this involves evaluating your function. Luckily we can turn this off with `NormalsFunction`:

```
cnt = 0;
Plot3D[a + b, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 2, 
  Mesh -> All, MaxRecursion -> 0, NormalsFunction -> None,
  EvaluationMonitor :> (cnt++)
];
cnt
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

I don't know where the extra 2 evaluations are coming from, but let's at least profile a function that takes 2 seconds to evaluate and see if we're at 12 seconds. Perhaps there are more options we can turn off.

```
Plot3D[Pause[2]; a + b, 
  {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 2, Mesh -> All, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, NormalsFunction -> None
]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {12.2104, Null}
> ```

---

If you'd like to have smooth shading, you could manually postprocess by estimating the surface normals from the triangular faces.

An example:

```
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 3π}, {y, 0, 3π}, 
  NormalsFunction -> None, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

```
(* hack to get the right plot style... *)
color = plot[[1, 2, 1, 1, 2]];

Show[DiscretizeGraphics[plot, MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> color}, 
  PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading"], AbsoluteOptions[plot]]
```

[image]

And for comparison, here's the plot with default shading:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 3π}, {y, 0, 3π}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find out what values a function is being evaluated at by making a definition such as

```
func[x_, y_] := (Print[{x, y}]; Sin[x y])

Timing[Plot3D[func[a, b], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 2, 
  Mesh -> All, MaxRecursion -> 0]]

{0,0}

{0.001001,0.001001}

{Charting`Private`pvar$3088,Charting`Private`pvar$3089}

{1.*10^-6,1.*10^-6}

{0.999999,1.*10^-6}

{1.*10^-6,0.999999}

{0.999999,0.999999}

{1.*10^-6,1.*10^-6}

{1.0149*10^-6,1.*10^-6}

{1.*10^-6,1.0149*10^-6}

{0.999999,1.*10^-6}

{0.999999,1.*10^-6}

{0.999999,1.0149*10^-6}

{1.*10^-6,0.999999}

{1.0149*10^-6,0.999999}

{1.*10^-6,0.999999}

{0.999999,0.999999}

{0.999999,0.999999}

{0.999999,0.999999}
```

Comment: You could also use `EvaluationMonitor`.